# Writing pandas dataframe into one excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to write the data from 2 excel files into one file. Of course the code below only writes the data from the first sheet into the consolidated sheet because the loop ends when writing the data from the first sheet. I think the solution is to keep the data from the first sheet, then append and then write to the sheet. But how? Today I'm too dumb finding the solution.

```
import pandas as pd

xlsInPath = "some path to sheets but all have one sheet with name 2019"
xlsFiles = ['test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx']
sheetName = ['2019']

df = pd.DataFrame({})

for xlsF in xlsFiles:
    FN = xlsInPath + xlsF
    print(FN)
    data1 = pd.read_excel(FN, sheet_name=sheetName, header=1, skiprows=0, engine='xlrd')
    print(data1)
    df.append(data1, ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.concat(data1)
    df.to_excel (r'C:\\Users\\A\\out\\Name.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Is the data in the first file being added to the second file, or are both being written to a new, third file? I’m confused as to what exactly the issue is here.

Comment: The at location xlsInPath consits 2 files ['test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx'] both with a sheetname ['2019']. The for loop should read both files and write the whole date into one file Name.xlsx into sheet_name='Sheet_name_1.

Comment: Okay, then what’s not working currently? Can’t you just make a DataFrame from each file, concat them, and write the result to a file? Depending on the number of files this program can take as input, I would suggest doing a single concat operation, at the end.

Comment: Added the solution below. A coallegue.helped me and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are writing the dataframe to excel in the loop. Move the last line in your loop outside the loop, then you will be pasting the entire dataframe into the spreadsheet at once instead of one sheet at a time. There may or may not be another problem in your code, but I would at least try that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
import pandas as pd

xlsInPath = "C:\\Users\\in\\"
xlsOutPath = "C:\\Users\\out\\"
xlsInFiles = ['test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx']
xlsOutFile = 'ConcatResult.xlsx'

sheetName = '2019'  
# must be string if only 1 worksheet otherwise a list of strings

df = pd.DataFrame()

for xlsF in xlsInFiles:
    FN = xlsInPath + xlsF
    print(FN)
    xd = pd.read_excel(FN, sheet_name=sheetName, header=0, skiprows=0, engine='xlrd')
    # needs header here line 0 first line to recognize the equal columns
    print('##XD\n', xd)

    df = pd.concat([df, xd], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)  
    # needs a list of concatanable DataFrames

print('##DF\n', df)
df.to_excel(r''+xlsOutPath+xlsOutFile, sheet_name=sheetName, index=False, header=1)
```

Comment: Do a single concat at the end, it should be more efficient that way.

Comment: See first posting

Comment: The issue had nothing to do with concat as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok, I‘ll try tomorrow. And yes, I agree the code could be modificated being more efficient.